# How can I install Openfiler on Vmware ESX 4.1?

Tags: vmware

How can I install [Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) on Vmware ESX 4.1? Is there a step-by-step guide?

Comment: There apear to be good [step by step guides](http://www.openfiler.com/learn/how-to/graphical-installation) on their site. Is there something missing from the usual documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just download the pre-made [VMware virtual machine](http://www.openfiler.com/community/download)?